# cannot login to ubuntu user account after setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Tags: 14.04, login

I have recently installed a software tool for develop a c++ code on ubuntu 14.04. When I tried to run the code it gave me a runtime error saying some shared library accessing problem. Then I set my `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` using following commands.

```
cd /etc/profile.d
sudo touch myenv_vars.sh
sudo gedit myenv_vars.sh
```

Then I set the path as

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
```

and saved it. After this, I logged out and tried to log in back. I know the password of my ubuntu user account but it gives me the same login screen again and again. So please can someone help me.

Answer (score 2):

With your script, you have overwritten the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` with only one path.

1. Start the grub menu by holding down the left <kbd>Shift</kbd> key during system start
2. Select the entry <kbd>Advanced …</kbd> and start the <kbd>Recovery mode</kbd>
3. Select <kbd>root</kbd>
4. Remove the file
5. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> and resume the boot process

For more information about `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` read [this article](http://prefetch.net/articles/linkers.badldlibrary.html).